# How can I call variable by string name

Tags: c#, system.reflection

In my application I am using variables with names like dp1,dp2,....dp13 in order to use them in loops and I want to call thame in a for loop. I want to use it something like given below.

```
DataPoint dp1,dp2,dp3,dp4,dp5;
string s1,s2,s3,s4,s5;
for(int i=1;i<=5,i++)
{
  GetVariable("dp"+i.ToString()).Add(val1, val2);
  GetVariable("s"+i.ToString())="MyStringValue";
}
```

How can I do that ? I saw at some places ask me to use System.Reflection but I don't know how to use it as I want

Comment: you should rethink your approach. Collections are actually build to do this. What is your main aim? and why do you have so many datapoints that are solely without beeing grouped in a collection

Comment: @MongZhu I have 13 DataPoints to control 13 different charts in real time.  And All the variables have indexes  likes dp1,dp2,dp3.... tb1,tb2,tb3... so instead of writing the same code 13 times I want to do it in a for loop.

Comment: @Austin I checked this one and from my understanding it is more like passing value of a variable to another variable. Or did I get it wrong ?

Comment: @MustafaOzbalci So using collections doesn't help you? ...

Comment: @Ergis I am sorry but I feel like I am not that familiar with usage of Collections usage for this case. Do you mind giving me a sample in usage?

Comment: `var dataPoints = new List<DataPoint>(); dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint()); // whatever you're doing for dp1` Later, `foreach (var dp in dataPoints) { dp.Add(val1, val2); }`.

Comment: Thank you @HereticMonkey I think I got how to use it

Comment: @MustafaOzbalci Can you post you GetVariable code pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<DataPoint> DataPoints = new List<DataPoints>();
List<string> strings = new List<string>();

DataPoints.Add(new DataPoint);
DataPoints.Add(new DataPoint);
DataPoints.Add(new DataPoint);
DataPoints.Add(new DataPoint);
DataPoints.Add(new DataPoint);

strings.Add("");
strings.Add("");
strings.Add("");
strings.Add("");
strings.Add("");

for(int i=1;i<=5,i++)
{
     DataPoints[i].Add(val1, val2);
     strings[i] = "MyStringValue";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will work

```
       List<DataPoint> DataPoints = new List<DataPoint>();
        List<string> Strings = new List<string>();

    
        double val1 = 1;
        double val2 = 2;
        
        int pointNumber = 13;
        do
        {
            DataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(val1, val2));
            Strings.Add("MyStringValue");
            pointNumber--;
        }
        while (pointNumber > 0);
```